# An entire function which is zero on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a Theorem in Complex Analysis saying the following:

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(z)=0$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the identity theorem is the theorem you are looking for !

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If $f, g$ holomorphic on a domain (open connected set) and equal on a sequence that converges to a point in their domain, then they are identical.

Comment: that should be an open connected set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The real Taylor series and complex Taylor series coincide, and the real Taylor series is identically zero, so then so is the complex one.